# Administrator user session only shows a terminal

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, command-line, login, login-screen

Weird problem:

After upgrading to 11.10 (and I am sure that I worked with it for couple of days).

We had a power failure, and now, when open the computer, what I get is a screen, with a scrollable list of users (administrator is one of them).
When I select the administrator user, and login, I get on the top left a terminal window.

That's it !

I don't see my regular ubuntu desktop.

What's wrong?

I have tried some of the issues mentioned here:

- Delete the .Xauthority
- sudo apt-get update

*I had some DNS errors, so had to fic my /etc/resolv.config  (works now)

please advise.

Comment: can you select another window manager for the user administrator when logging in? this helpt to find out, whether maybe only a config of the window manager is broken. However, what window manager did you select (e.g. Unity 2D, Unity 3D, gnome classic, ...?)?

Comment: sorry. con't comment on which I use. I am almsot positive it's the default: Unity 2D.

Comment: you can see your selection on the login screen after you clicked on the user name but before commiting the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a couple of days to notice that. on the Login screen, underneath the gear in the upper right corner of the password prompt window, "Recovery Session" was selected. "Ubuntu" or "Ubuntu 2D" are probably what you want, if you have the same problem I did.

Comment: After I manually changed the Display Manager, i noticed these options as well. Thanks.